# retrieve the main request url in OnAuthenticationFailed in owin using environment variable or other method

Tags: c#, .net, openid-connect, owin, okta

I have an old .net application. I am implementing OIDC with Owin. This application is not MVC.
Please note there is a third party app that does the authentication with IM tool Okt as single sign on.

In my application which I try to implement OIDC. In this application I have a public page
Meaning everyone can access as anonymous so if the user has not yet signed in the user can access it as anonymous and we do not run .challenge) however if the user has already signed in through my IM/security application I need to show this page as authenticated to user if user has proper access to see this app.
As a result I need to execute

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge.
```

This works nicely if my user is authenticated and has proper access to the app in Okta as the claim will return back and I can show the page as authenticate to the user.
Now if the user is signed in but does not have access to this app Owin takes me to OnAuthenticationFailed in startup page and it tries to redirect me to the error page.
In this case I want it to not do anything and skip and show me the page as unauthenticated.

I took a look at context in **OnAuthenticationFailed** method to see if it give me any value from which page I came and it does not.
Is there anything that I can use to determine that because if I have then I can ignore this particular public page.

I tried to set the environment variable in

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
   var request = context.Request;

   IDictionary<string, object> environment = context.Environment;

   // Add a custom value to the environment

     environment["RedirectUriForFailure"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

     return next();
});
```

and then retrieve in the onAuthenticationFailed method but it will not show up in the environment variable.

```
IDictionary<string, object> environment = context.Request.Environment;
var test = environment["RedirectUriForFailure"];
 test is empty
```

Any idea or suggestion to how to determine from which URL my request is originating in OnAuthenticationFailed would be highly appreciated.

Comment: private Task  OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> arg)
{
    object obj = null;
    if (arg.OwinContext.Environment.TryGetValue("mytest", out obj))
    {    
          string flag = obj as string;
    }
    arg.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("myNewParameter", "its Value");

    return Task.CompletedTask;
 } and then tried to retrieve the env variavle parameter in OnAuthenticationFailed no luck both are e mpty

Answer (score 0):

You can create Concurrent dictionary in earlier stages and access it in OnAuthenticationFailed